# How to use firebase "ref" inside a controller

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase

I made a factory in service.js file

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://loginmy-reddit.firebaseio.com');

   return $firebaseAuth(ref);

})

.service('BlankService', [function(){

}]);
```

I want to use the ref for logging out the user  which is in my main.js file

```
    angular.module('app')
   .controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,$state,Auth){

    $scope.login = function(authMethod){
        Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup(authMethod).then(function(authdata){
            console.log(authdata);
            $scope.signedInUser = authdata;
             $state.go('menu.home');
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    }       
        $scope.logout=function(){
        ref.unauth();

        //state.go('main');
        }
```

How can i logout the user retaining the ref in service.js file..

Comment: You can add the unauth in the service as a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your current service a bit like this:

```
.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://loginmy-reddit.firebaseio.com');
    return {
        login: function(){
            return $firebaseAuth(ref);
        },
        logout: function () {
            ref.unauth()
        }
    }
})
```

And use it in your controller like this:

```
$scope.login = function(authMethod){
    Auth.login().$authWithOAuthPopup(authMethod).then(function(authdata){
        console.log(authdata);
        $scope.signedInUser = authdata;
         $state.go('menu.home');
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
}       
    $scope.logout=function(){
    Auth.logout();

    //state.go('main');
    }
```

Comment: There should be a checkmark next to the answer, just click that and it will turn green :)